# Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, checksum

I have a **Master Detail** form in my **Oracle APEX** application. When I am trying to update data in this form, I am getting below error.

> Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated
>   update process. current row version identifier =
>   "26D0923D8A5144D6F483C2B9815D07D3" application row version identifier
>   = "1749BCD159359424E1EE00AC1C3E3FCB" (Row 1)

I have cleared browser cache and try to update. But it not worked.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This can be tricky - try refreshing the page (i.e. reload from the server) and retrying. Otherwise some tips here might help: https://forums.oracle.com/message/11029554

Comment: "A key value was declared as 'hidden' under the Report Attributes section of the Region declaration. Having a column declared 'Hidden' causes a conflict with the apex_application.g_f0x array! This array is used during the MRU or 'update' phase. That is why the error was occurring for me. To those who may have redeclared their primary key, it may have been set to 'hidden'! If you do not want to display your primary key, then set the value to 'Display as Text, Saves State', then set Show Column to 'No'."

Comment: @Bishan - I have a Tabular Form (not Master-Detail like the original note) where I tried your suggestion about the key value as hidden affecting the MRU process.  That didn't help.

Side-note: A user just reported this error to me for the first time on a Tabular Form that's been running in Production for 2 years without a change. At first it felt like if I filter the data down to a small set of rows (under 1200), it worked, but over that it failed?  But it's not consistent.

I tried adjusting the report's Maximum Row Count, but that didn't help.

Comment: I also noticed that the Save bug occurs when I change the first few records displayed. But if I change the 4th, 5th or more record, Save worked!  Weird.  So my short-term workaround at the moment is to make sure the users filter the results below 1,000 records. I think in the longer term, I'm going to change this from a Tabular Form to a Report-Form, so the form is only updating a single row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar problem where my detail records set has timestamp fields. By default master detail wizard creates the timestamp fields as date picker type fields. If you set the date format on these, it would resolve the issue.

Comment: Also if you like to show these date/timestamp columns then show as display only does not save the state.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post tries to address this issue on a Tabular Form (I know that's not what the original issue was with, but thought it might be related). It says the same as @sangam does below.

Short version: If you have an updated field that's timestamp datatype, you should set a date/time format.

http://apexbyg.blogspot.com/2015/05/tabular-form-bug.html

My tabular form has a field that's timestamp datatype, but I had already set a date format, so this didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility, which I discovered was the case in my application.

That would be if the data the original checksum was calculated on is truly different than the pre-update checksum calculation, due to a design-flaw in your query!

In my application, the source for one of the updateable fields was `COALESCE(name_calced, name_preferred)`. In the source table, the person's name could already be loaded in the record by an external process and we save it to one field - *name_calced*.  But the end-user can enter a preferred name, which we wanted to save to the **name_preferred** field.  We wanted to initially populate the displayed, updateable tabular form field with *name_calced*, if one existed, or *name_preferred* if the user had already provided a preferred name.  Then they could change that value and save it back to the database.

I finally discovered that the Save action threw the error message if **name_calced** was non-null, but *name_preferred* was null. I realized that the initial checksum was calculated based on *name_calced*, but the pre-update checksum was based on *name_preferred*, so the application thought someone had changed the value in the background and showed the error message.

**What I don't understand** is how this problem didn't show up in the past 3 years the application has been running in production!

**My solution** is to make the field source only on **name_preferred**, which immediately solved this problem.  I also think the back-end process will also get changed to pre-populate that table field from **name_calced**, so the user always sees the base value, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue myself. Now, I realize that tabular forms are deprecated at this time, but I have an application that was developed beforehand and still uses them. This issue occurred and I had to get one of our big guns at Oracle to help me out. I do a lot of DB work and a decent amount of Apex development but I'm more of a Java, WebLogic, etc guy, and I really couldn't figure this one out.

In my case, it turned out to be really simple. One of the columns in my tabular form was a hidden field, generated via a sub query. Being hidden, this column is not editable by the user and should not be part of the MRU update. I had the field set to "Hidden Column (saves states)" and setting its type to "Hidden Column" fixed the issue. So, this leads to sub queries being executed in such a way as to change the checksum for the overall query before hitting submit (save), causing the error.

For those who are continuing to troubleshoot this, look at your query for every field that you have specified and note which columns are editable in the tabular form. All other fields should be set in a way that makes them not save state so that they are not part of the update.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I had two update processes processing on submit.

My solution was to add a condition to both processing steps. I had forgotten to do this when I made an additional process for Button A, but I never updated Button B to limit it's behaviors.

Navigation:
Processing -> Processes -> [Your Process Name] -> Server-side Condition -> When Button Pressed = [Your button Name]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a column from a secondary table that was not set as Query Only and was being updated! The error would occur trying to save a column not in the table being updated. It took me half a day to figure it out (the column names were the same).

Answer (score 0):

Set your Link column hidden to display only in the form.

Set "Send On Page Submit" to 'No' or disable the link column that is your primary key ( Rownum/rowid/id etc).

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score -2):

I have noticed this error comes when I was working Tabular Form and has disabled one of the form operations i.e. by setting server-side condition to "Never" for add, apply changes (submit) buttons

When I have restored back to its original state, it worked as expected.

In case you have to hide Add/Update button, use some other option.

https://compknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2018/12/oracle-apex-error-current-version-of.html